# Image in <a> not working after applying hover effects

Tags: html, css, hover

first of all, here's my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BbklG.

After applying my hover effects, the image link isn't clickable.

How do I make my image clickable while maintaining this hover effect? Thanks!

```
<div class="view view-sixth">
   <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="http://static.oprah.com/images/200212/omag/200212-omag-ripple-effect-600x411.jpg" border="0"></a>
   <div class="mask">
       <h2>Image Description</h2>                
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.view {
   margin:0 auto;
   width: 350px;
   height: 230px;   
   float: left;   
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   cursor: default;
   background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 350px;
   height: 230px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.view h2 {
   font-family: "Lato";
   font-weight: 300;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #fff;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;   
   font-size: 30px;    
}
.view-sixth img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.view-sixth .mask {
  pointer-events:none;
   background-color: rgba(230,203,226,0.7);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;   
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0.1s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0.1s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0.1s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0.1s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0.1s;
}
.view-sixth h2 {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;   
   background: transparent;
   margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
   -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
   -o-transform: scale(2.5);
   -ms-transform: scale(2.5);
   transform: scale(2.5);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.view-sixth:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s;
}
.view-sixth:hover h2 {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your elements in `a` or simply add this line to your CSS:

```
.view-sixth .mask {
  pointer-events:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason the image is not clickable is because your "mask" div is covering right over it.  You are using absolute positioning to put a block level element over the top of another block element.

I would suggest wrapping the mask div inside the anchor tag with the image see how that works.

Answer (score -1):

```
       <div class="view view-sixth">
        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="http://static.oprah.com/images/200212/omag/200212-omag-ripple-effect-600x411.jpg" border="0">
        <div class="mask">
            <h2>Image Description</h2>                
        </div></a>
        </div>
```

You missed a closing div and your closing a tag was in the wrong place works with the above code.